# Django Admin Create Form Inline OneToOne

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have the following model:

```py
from django.db import models


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_password_reset = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    needs_password_reset = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=500, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
```

I am trying to inline this into the admin. I have the following:

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    """User profile inline."""

    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = "Profile"


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    """Create user form."""

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "first_name", "last_name", "email")


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    """Custom user admin."""

    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    inlines = (UserProfileInline,)


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

This is working fine up to a point; when I go to create user, I can see the inlined profile information. However, when I try to submit the form I get the following error (on `/admin/auth/user/add/`):

```py
psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Why is the `user_id` field not getting populated in the inline form? How can I set this attribute to the `id` of the user created by the form?

Comment: There might be an issue with how the database is set up. I just recreated your project locally, and I was able to successfully create users without this exception. Which form submission is raising the exception? User creation, or update?

Comment: are `UserCreationForm` and `UserAdmin` coming from `django.contrib.auth.forms` and `django.contrib.auth.admin`, respectively, or are those custom versions?

Comment: @jimijimjim I just updated the question to include some additional information; it's failing on user creation

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to remove some signals I had written for automatic profile creation:

```py
# Create a profile for new users
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)


# Update profile on user change
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Comment: What have the signals to do with the object creation? Did you simply delete them?