# Error with inlined profile form save in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I really confised, because problem sounds trivial, but I didn't googled anything related to this. I found one very simular question [Django Admin Create Form Inline OneToOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56465018/django-admin-create-form-inline-onetoone) but in my case I cannot remove signal, it'll break normal way of user creation in my app.
I have model User and Profile connected OneToOne relationship (models.py):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .managers import UserManager

class User(AbstractUser):
    """auth/login-related fields"""
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email 

class Profile(models.Model):
    """profile fields"""
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
    telegram = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('save profile', args, kwargs) # from admin it run 2 times, second with empty args, kwargs so PROBLEM HERE!!!
        print('save profile complete')

"""receivers to add a Profile for newly created users"""
@receiver(post_save, sender=User) 
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print('create_user_profile', created, instance.id)
    if created:
        try:
            p = Profile.objects.create(user = instance)
            print('succsecc!!!!', p, p.id) ## here profile object created and got id
        except Exception as e:
            print('create profile error', e) # never prints
    else:
        instance.profile.save()

""" @receiver(post_save, sender=User) 
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print('save_user_profile')
    try:
        instance.profile.save()
    except Exception:
            print('save profile error', Exception)
 """
```

This models works well from frontend of my application, users register and fill their profiles, everything OK.
Problem occur when I try to make user from django admin. Then I getting `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: authenticate_profile.user_id.`

My admin.py file looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm, ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import Profile
from .forms import SignUpForm

User = get_user_model()

class UserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = True
    verbose_name = Profile

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        print('save_model profile', request.POST, obj, form, change) ## never prints
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)    

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = SignUpForm
    form = UserChangeForm
    model = User
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name' 'password1', 'password2')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff', 'is_active')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_staff', 'is_active')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    inlines = (UserInline, )

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        print('save_model user', request.POST, obj, form, change)
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)



admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Code in post_save signal successfully runs, and creates profile, after that  django tries to save profile from inlined form, and fails with this error `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed authenticate_profile.user_id`. From logs I see, Profile.save(), when I create user from admin, called twice, second time without args and kwargs. But when I override save method of profile model, not to run `super().save()` without arguments, I have no errors, but I unable to save profile both from admin and frontend. So problem lies in this method - HOW TO OVERRIDE IT TO WORK BOTH FROM ADMIN AND NORMAL WORKFLOW?. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your User post_save signal you call profile.save() without arguments when it updates User. Try removing that.

Comment: The problem is that since you have an inline profile, you’re creating it explicitly when saving the user. And it’s a new one, not an existing one because when the form is instantiated there isn’t an existing profile to use. So what you want isn’t going to work. You can’t create user and profile at the same time from admin. Or you shouldn’t auto-create an empty profile, only create it when it actually is needed.

Comment: Johan Schiff removing profile.save() didn't change anything, still the same error

Answer (score 0):

That was tricky... I think you forgot quotes around verbose_name. should be

```
class UserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = True
    verbose_name = 'Profile'
```

Comment: It didn't change anything

Comment: I can not reproduce than. I have similar setup as yours, and it works without problems

Answer (score 0):

the email field unique will give you problems I advise using

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
email =forms.EmailField(label='Your Email')
class Meta:
    model= User
    fields = ['username','email','password1', 'password2']
    
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
    user_count = User.objects.filter(email=email).count()
    if user_count > 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError('This email has already been taken')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a workaound. I divided the data entry into two steps.

In the administration, I first create only the `User` object and the `Profile` object is created using the signal. Only when both objects are created, I also display `UserInline` (name `ProfileInline` would be more accurate).

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    model = User

  def get_inlines(self, request, obj=None):
      if obj:
          return [UserInline,]
      else:
          return []
```